# SPQuery AppendOnly field returns null

Tags: 2010, object-model

I have a list with an custom append only field for collecting comments from supervisors.  When I query the list using SPQuery I always get null back for the value of the append only field. I have tried explicitly requesting that field with setting

```
query.ViewFields
```

All of my other values come back fine, and I am able to view the comments via the out of the box functionality through the web ui.

Comment: Make sure you are using the internal name of the field. Show some more code...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by iterating through the versions of the item and when I find the first value I push it into my custom object.

```
        int i = 0;
        foreach (SPListItemVersion oVersion in myListItem.Versions)
        {
          String s = Convert.ToString(myListItem.Versions[i]["SiteColumn_SupervisorSummary"]);
          if (s.Trim() != String.Empty)
          {
            myObject.SupervisorSummary = s;
            break;
          }
          i++;
        }
```

AppendOnly fields will only work if versioning is turned on the list.  The latest version of the item is available at listItem.Versions[0] however, in that version, my field was null.  My assumption is that the versioning of list items saves deltas and the lastest version had some other change than the Supervisor Summary.